# how to find ker f of a linear application

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

I have a linear application:
$$f:R_{\le 2}[x]\longrightarrow R_{\le 2}[x]$$
$$ax^2+bx+c \mapsto (ka+3b+c)x^2+(a+3b+kc)x+(a+3kb+c)$$

with $ k \in R$.

It is asked to find a base for $Im F$ and $Ker f$.

Considering the base $ x^2, x, 1 $ of $R_{\le 2}[x]$, the associated matrix to the application is:
$$
A=\begin{Bmatrix} k & 3  & 1 \\ 1 & 3  & k \\ 1 & 3k  & 1  \end{Bmatrix}
$$

**Is it allowed to transform the matrix A in $A=\begin{Bmatrix} k & 1  & 1 \\ 1 & 1  & k \\ 1 & k  & 1  \end{Bmatrix}$?**

If $k \ne 1,-2$ , $r(A)=3=dim Im f$ , $B_{Im f}=<(kx^2+x+1);(x^2+x+k),(x^2+kx+1)>$,
$dim Ker f=0$

If $k = 1$ ,
 $r(A)=1=dim Im f$ ,
 $B_{Im f}=<(x^2+x+1)>$  and $dim Ker f=2$.

But I have some difficulties to find a base for $ker f$
I know that I should solve the associated linear homogeneous system, but perhaps I'm a bit confused because there are polynomials
Could someone explain how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The "kernel" of linear transformation from vector space U to vector space V is the subspace of U consisting of all vectors, u, in U such that Au= 0.

Here, that means we must have $ka+ 3b+ c= 0$, $a+ 3b+ kc= 0$, and $a+ 3kb+ c= 0$.  Solve those equation for a, b, and c.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that the vectors $v_1 = (1, -1, 0)^T$ and $v_2 = (1, 0, -1)^T$ are solutions to the system $Av = 0$. Since $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent and $dim~Ker(A) = 2$, they form a basis for the kernel of $A$.

Now the only thing left is to figure out to what polynomials $v_1$ and $v_2$ correspond to. Since your basis is $x^2, x, 1$, the first entry of the vectors is the coefficient of $x^2$, the second is the coefficient of $x$ and the last the coefficient of $1$. Therefore, the basis of the kernel is $x^2-x$ and $x^2-1$.

You can verify this by mapping the polynomials using your map: $x^2-x \rightarrow (1-1)x^2 + (1-1)x = 0$ and so on.

Edit: I think the matrix of your mapping is incorrect. In my verification I'm using the form given by the matrix, but in the actual mapping you gave this would be $x^2-x \rightarrow (1-3)x^2+(1-3)x \neq 0$.